# create files through terminal and joining two files in script python3

Tags: linux, python-3.6

I have a recursive directory called 'dir'. I am writing to list of files from all subdirectories to a CSV file with the following command in linux on the terminal.

```
dir$ find . -type f -printf '%f\n' > old_names.csv
```

I am using a detox code to change filenames. And I am making a new list using

```
dir $ find . -type f -printf '%f\n' > new_names.csv
```

I would like to join this to lists together and make a new list with two columns something like this;

[image]

To do that I read both csv files into pandas data frame and join them on index as follows in python3 script

```
 import pandas as pd
 import csv

 df_old=pd.read_csv(os.path.join(somepath,'old_names.csv')
 df_new=pd.read_csv(os.path.join(somepath,'new_names.csv')
 df_names=df_new.join(df_old)
```

The problem is I am getting something like this, wrong file pairs;

[image]

When I open the new_names.csv I see that file list is written in a different order than old_names list so joining on index resulting in wrong pairs. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How about `paste old_names.csv new_names.csv`?

Comment: How are you getting different names in the two files? You're creating them with the same command in the same directory.

Comment: How are you ordering the two files, so that corresponding rows are the old and new name for the same file?

Comment: Hi! Thanks Barmar. First, I create the old file name list, then I run a script which goes to that folder change the filenames to detox them. Now in the terminal, I go to the same folder and create a new list of changed names. I don`t do any ordering, when i create the lists with the command line it does the ordering.

Comment: There's no reason to expect that `find` will print the files in the same order after you do all the renaming.

Comment: In fact, I think it's very unlikely to do so.

Answer (score 0):

To isolate the problem, it's best to check old_names.csv and new_names.csv first to see if they are indeed in the same order. If that's indeed the problem, it's better to map filename to actual content of the file, e.g. checksum or something similar. There are 2 ways:

### Method 1

Replace the find command with script below.

1. Save the script below somewhere easy to find, maybe a level outside of your dir so it doesn't get detoxed. Let's call it 'get_sha_name_csv.py'.

```
import glob
import hashlib
import pandas
import sys

def get_df():
    '''

    :param dir_address:
    :return:
    '''
    files = glob.glob('*.*')
    hash_dict = []
    for file in files:
        with open(file, 'rb') as f:
            data = f.read()
        hash_dict.append({'sha256': hashlib.sha256(data).hexdigest(), 'filename':file})
    return pandas.DataFrame(hash_dict)

output_name = sys.argv[1]
get_df().to_csv(output_name)
```

2. Call it from terminal:

```
dir$ python ../get_sha_name_csv.py ../old_names.csv
```

The second argument is the name of your output csv file.

3. do detox stuff
4. call

```
dir$ python ../get_sha_name_csv.py ../new_names.csv
```

5. merge them with

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

df_old=pd.read_csv(os.path.join(somepath,'old_names.csv')
df_new=pd.read_csv(os.path.join(somepath,'new_names.csv')
pd.merge(df_new, df_old, on='sha256', how='outer')
```

### Method 2

Do everything in python

```
import glob
import hashlib
import pandas
import os

def get_df(dir_address):
    # this function gives you the dataframe with sha256-to-filename mapping

    files = glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_address,'*.*'))
    hash_dict = []
    for file in files:
        with open(file, 'rb') as f:
            data = f.read()
        hash_dict.append({'sha256': hashlib.sha256(data).hexdigest(), 'filename':file}) # can replace with other hashfunctions
    return pandas.DataFrame(hash_dict)

def main(dir_address):
    # get old sha256-to-filename df
    df = get_df(dir_address)

    # run your detox code here, possibly with subprocess module (this part is untested)
    subprocess.run(['detox'], cwd=dir_address)

    # get new sha256-to-filename df and merge on sha256 values
    new_df = get_df(dir_address)
    output = pandas.merge(df, new_df, on='sha256', how='outer')
    print(output)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main(PUT_YOUR_DIRECTORY_LOCATION_HERE)
```